# MongoDB replica set Network Interface exceeded time limit

Tags: mongodb-3.6

I am using MongoDB version 3.6.12 and saw one of running secondary node keeps getting this error from log:

```
2019-09-23T12:24:48.921-0400 I REPL     [replication-791] Restarting oplog query due to error: NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: error in fetcher batch callback: Operation timed out. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts: Timestamp(1569254987, 1), t: 26 }[-1363109028778963646]. Restarts remaining: 1
2019-09-23T12:24:55.922-0400 I REPL     [replication-791] Error returned from oplog query (no more query restarts left): NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: error in fetcher batch callback: Operation timed out
2019-09-23T12:24:55.923-0400 W REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Fetcher stopped querying remote oplog with error: NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: error in fetcher batch callback: Operation timed out
```

However, in Mongo shell rs.status() showing all nodes are healthy. Restarting the mongod instance running on the problem node solved the issue.

Anyone know what is the most likely cause of this problem?

Comment: This error causing our MongoDB replica set out of sync and rs.status() doesn't show any error. I only noticed there is problem when some documents can be read from Primary node but not exist in secondary node. Is that a bug in Mongo?